# Calculate thickness of individual objects in edge map

Tags: python

I am searching for a long time on net.But no use.Please help or try to give some ideas howto achieve his.
case1:I used an edge detection algorithm to get an edge map as follows, but now I don't quite understand how to calculate the thickness of each object in this edge map: can I first perform instance segmentation and then calculate the thickness of each instance individually? If anyone can answer me I would be very grateful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICC7c.png)

I am searching for a long time on net.But no use.Please help or try to give some ideas howto achieve his.